# Swift. Proper initialization of UITableViewCell hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

[UITableViewCell] <- [genericCell] <- [Cell1], [Cell2], [Cell3]

Hello. Please imagine hierarchy above. In my code I don't have objects exactly of type `genericCell`, but this class shares some properties.

What design of inits should be in my code? I have following structure for genericCell:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //my stuff (initializing shared properties)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

But what about `Cell1`? How can I invoke `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` in `genericCell` for "my stuff" operations through initialisation of `Cell1` instance? Now they doesn't perform.

---

**EDIT**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let typeOfCell = FbDataManager.sharedInstance.posts[indexPath.row][FbDataManager.sharedInstance.typeParameter] as! String

        switch typeOfCell {
            case self.linkTypeOfPost:

                var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.linkCellIdentifier) as? FbLinkPostViewCell
                if cell == nil {
                    cell = FbLinkPostViewCell.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: self.linkCellIdentifier)
                }
//...
```

Hi again. This is part from tableView's delegate, btw I copy-pasted Abhinav's inits to my code and again those inits aren't working. (no output to console)

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it seems to be about inheritance between classes. So basically you have a "GenericCell" class that inherits from "UITableViewCell", and "CellOne", "CellTwo", and "CellThree" classes that each inherit from "GenericCell". If you want to go through *init with style*, one way to set this up would be like this:

```
class GenericCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // code common to all your cells goes here
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class CellOne: GenericCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // the common code is executed in this super call
        // code unique to CellOne goes here
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

You could then create instances of CellOne in your table view's data source like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = CellOne.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    return cell!
}
```

For each instance it will now first go through the common setup done in "GenericCell", and then through the unique setup in "CellOne". "CellTwo" and "CellThree" would be set up accordingly.

**EDIT**

A more concrete example of how to configure instances of all three Cell types:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // you need to write a method like this to figure out which type you need:
        let cellID = self.cellIDForIndexPath(indexPath) // returns either "cell1", "cell2" or "cell3"

        // dequeue or init a cell of the approriate type
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)
        if (cell == nil) {
            switch cellID {
                case "cell1": cell = CellOne.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
                case "cell2": cell = CellTwo.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
                case "cell3": cell = CellThree.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
                default: cell = UITableViewCell()
            }

        }

        // configure the individual cell if needed (you need to implement methods + logic here that fit your data)
        (cell as! GenericCell).configureForData(self.dataForIndexPath(indexPath))

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't `if` block in my code just like you wrote. So does `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` invokes `init` like in `if` branch?

Comment: No. The idea of reusable cells is that they are only initialized once and then reused. So `init` is only called if the cell hasn't previously been initialized (i.e. if we hit the content of the `if`). You would have to differentiate your cell classes with the identifier: check which class you need for the index, then check (with a unique identifier like "cell1", "cell2" and "cell3") if that particular type can be `deqeue`d or needs to be initialised. If there are multiple cells of the same class (e.g. 3 "CellOne"s) that need to be configured individually, I would create a new method for that.

Comment: Added some code to the answer that hopefully makes it more clear how this approach would work with your setup.

Comment: cell = CellOne.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell") works ! I have been trying with let cell = WebTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "webviewCell") without the .init and took me a while to get around. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would lay down the hierarchy mentioned by you:

**Step 1 :** Make Generic Cell class

```
class GenericCell : UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print("Generic Cell Initialization Done")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**Step 2 :** Make Specific Cell 1 class:

```
class MyCell1 : GenericCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print("MyCell1 Initialization Done")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**Step 3 :** Make Specific Cell 2 class:

```
class MyCell2 : GenericCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print("MyCell2 Initialization Done")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**Step 4 :** Make Specific Cell 3 class:

```
class MyCell3 : GenericCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print("MyCell3 Initialization Done")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**Step 5 :** Finally use the cells like this:

```
let cell1 = MyCell1.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")
let cell2 = MyCell2.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")
let cell3 = MyCell3.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell3")
```

**PS: This would guarantee setting the properties in generic cell as well in specific cells.**

**EDIT:** This is how you would use cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell1

        if cell1 == nil {
            cell1 = MyCell1.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        }

        // Do your cell property setting

        return cell1
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell2

        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = MyCell2.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")
        }

        // Do your cell property setting

        return cell2
    } else {
        let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell3

        if cell3 == nil {
            cell3 = MyCell3.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell3")
        }

        // Do your cell property setting

        return cell3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I have the code just like you wrote. Seems like it is something around "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" method. Please look at my comment on next answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how it should look on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. When a `UITableView` instance calls for `dequeueReusableTileWithIdentifier:`, the cell is not reinitialized. Instead, in that call, the `UITableViewCell` that is dequeued will call `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: How can I add a custom parameter to those inizializations?