# Swift: can't configure custom table cell programmatically? Init not called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Alright, I am trying to add content to my custom tableview cell programmatically as demonstrated in mob last question here - [Swift: tableview cell content is added again and again with each reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135512/swift-tableview-cell-content-is-added-again-and-again-with-each-reload?noredirect=1#comment65616366_39135512) initializing all the content in func tableView() results in overlapping.

I have followed this question verbatim  [Swift. Proper initialization of UITableViewCell hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317158/swift-proper-initialization-of-uitableviewcell-hierarchy) And in my custom cell class (which I give a name to in my storyboard) I have:

```
class EventTableCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) // the common code is executed in this super call
        // code unique to CellOne goes here
        print("INIT")
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }
```

And this init is not called because nothing is printed. The errors come in my func tableView() in my main VC. I originally had:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableCellTableViewCell
//        cell.eventTitle.text = names[indexPath.row]
//        cell.eventDescription.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]

        cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false

        //cell UIX
        let eventTitleLabel = UILabel()
        let dateLabel = UILabel()
        let authorLabel = UILabel()
        let locationLabel = UILabel()

        let categoryView = UIImageView()
//then I add everything
```

But this didn't work so I looked at other posts and now have:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableCellTableViewCell

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = EventTableCellTableViewCell.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
        }
```

I have also tried doing it without the indexPath. Right now I get an error that cell cannot == nil, and not matter what I write init is not called.

How can I configure my cell programmatically?

Comment: Partially unrelated but `UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` never returns `nil`.

Comment: If cell class represent cell from storyboard then use `awakeFromNib` method for initialization

Comment: Given the question you reference, it seems like you're trying to do this without a storyboard.  Is that so?  If not, @vadian's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: @rmaddy if dequeueReusableCell never returns nil, how can you know when you need to call the init and when it can reuse the cell?
I have a custom init (with my own parameters) and I am not sure how to call it and still being able to reuse the cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cell is designed in the storyboard only `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called, `init(style: style, reuseIdentifier:` is never called.

And you have to set the class of the cell in Interface Builder to `EventTableCellTableViewCell`.